# No puedo acceder a un método protegido desde una sub clase PHP POO

Tags: php, poo, php7, clase, herencia

Aver, tengo una duda, y teoricamente creo que se me esta escapando algo..

En principio, **todos los métodos** **de la clase padre** que sean **publicos** **o protegidos** , pueden ser heredados por sus hijos.

Vale pues a mi no me esta heredando bien un método protected..

```
class Automovil{  // CLASE PADRE
    protected function llenarDeposito($euros, $precio_litro){
        $litros_repostados = round($euros / $precio_litro, 2);
        echo "Repostando 20€... Has repostado ".$litros_repostados." litros <br>";
        $this->deposito = $litros_repostados;
        array_push($this->respostajes, [$euros, $precio_litro, $litros_repostados]);
    }
}
class Deportivo extends Automovil {  // SUBCLASE
    private $marca;
    private $motor_encendido = false;
    private $deposito = 0;
    private $consumo = 6;
    public $respostajes = [];
    private $viajes = [];

    public function __construct($marca, $consumo_100_km_en_litros){
        $this->marca = $marca;
        $this->consumo = $consumo_100_km_en_litros;
    }
   
}

$coche = new Deportivo("Mercedes", 6);
$coche->llenarDeposito(35, 1.30);  // Aqui da el error
```

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to protected method Automovil::llenarDeposito() from context '' in C:\Users\Julian Dept Web\Documents\nueva-web\repositorios\proyecto_coche_poo\index.php:73 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Julian Dept Web\Documents\nueva-web\repositorios\proyecto_coche_poo\index.php on line 73
```

Comment: Ni private ni protected pueden ser accedidas fuera de la clase. Private solo puede ser accedida dentro de la propia clase y protected dentro de la clase y clases heredadas, pero no fuera. Necesitas un método público que acceda al método protected (o privado) y retorne (get) o introduzca (set) los valores que necesitas.

Comment: Toda la razón, no había caido que la estaba llamando desde fuera!..... Ponlo como respuesta y te doy el voto

Comment: ¿Por qué declaras `llenarDeposito()` como `protected` si por lo que parece necesitas acceder a ese método desde fuera de la clase? ¿No sería mejor declarlarlo como `public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los métodos `private` o `protected` no pueden ser accedidas fuera de la clase. `private` solo puede ser accedida dentro de la propia clase y `protected` dentro de la clase y clases heredadas, pero no fuera.

Puedes crear un método público que acceda al método `protected`, o `private`, para que retorne (**get**) o introduzca (**set**) los valores que necesitas a la clase.

Más información: [Visibilidad POO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)